# How to validate in unsupervised domain adaptation

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, data-science

Here is the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_adaptation#The_different_types_of_domain_adaptation) in wikipedia:

> The unsupervised domain adaptation: the learning sample contains a set of labeled source examples, a set of unlabeled source examples and an unlabeled set of target examples.

Since we do not have labelled data on the target domain (even validation set), how can we decide whether a transfer procedure is finished? Or is overfitted/underfitted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a paper that might work in most transfer learning cases: [Cross Validation Framework to Choose amongst Models and Datasets for Transfer Learning](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-15939-8_35).

Answer (score 1):

To evaluating the model for academic purpose, we generally use labeled data for target samples, dropping the labels and evaluate the model with labels.

In the condition of which we cannot get target labels, we can evaluate the convergence with loss function related with domains.

For some algorithms which domain-overlapping loss is hidden, such as DANN / RevGrad, we can add the distance(similarity) term for embeddings of both domain, and can determine whether training converges with measuring it.